# Python issue with using Windows Path to create hyperlink in email

Tags: python, hyperlink, html-email

I have a path in the format of:

```
\\server1\path1\path2\path3
```

I'm using the python email module to place this path in a hyperlink, the html portion of my code looks like

```
    #import Email modules etc...
    message=MIMEMultipart()

    message['From']="me"
    message['To']="someone"
    message['Subject']="Stuff"
    html = """\
                            <html>
                              <head></head>
                              <body>
                                <p>
                                   Here is the link<br>
                                   <a href="\\server1\path1\path2\path3">View Folder_"""+str(datetime.datetime.now())[:10]+"""</a>
                                </p>
                              </body>
                            </html>
                            """
    part1= MIMEText(html,'html')

    message.attach(part1)
    mailer=smtplib.SMTP("something.server")
    mailer.sendmail(message['From'],message['To'],message.as_string())
```

The email sends without any problems...but in the message body there is no link, the recipient just sees

```
Here is the link 
View Folder_today's date (but no hyperlink pointing to the folder)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated..I'm just suspecting this may be due to the Windows File path, but I'm not sure.

Comment: IIRC paths in python need a `\\ ` at each level of the path because the single `\ ` is the escape character, so you need to escape it first. I would try replacing your `\ ` with `\\ `

Comment: Just tested this in a HTML file opened in Chrome and it renders fine, so it's probably your e-mail client/browser. Try prepending the path with `file:`, so it's `file:\\server1\path1\path2\path3`

Comment: I attempted each of the suggestions above and it still doesn't display the link...i got it working for a web URL like http://.. etc... but not for windows path, yet

Comment: I tried, file:\\, file://, file://// , \\\\server1\\path1\path2 ...all fails. I noticed that when I do manually open it in Chrome, the URL appears as file://server1/path2/path3 but i can't get it to hyperlink through python. Any more suggestions would be really appreciated.